# Add column in R based on condition 4

Tags: r

I have 4 columns and want to add a new column on a certain condition.
when the third column is 0 then the output is equal to the first column. when the third column is 1 then the output is equal to the second column. appreciate any help.

Example:

G   A    0   1   -->  G

A   G    1   1   -->  G

C   G    1   1   -->  G

Comment: Is this essentially just an array? As in each of your columns has one item?

Comment: ja, its a dataframe and each columns has one item

Comment: Take a look at the `ifelse()` function. I think that should work.

Comment: ja, I tried it, but however numbers are the output instead characters

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: df$new1 <- ifelse(df$V3 == 1, df$V2, df$V1)

Comment: `ifelse` works too and is only one line, but see my answer below for the more explicit `if` and `else if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your character columns are actually factors. You have to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when you are generating the dataframe.

```
a<-as.character(c("a","b","a"))
b<-as.character(c("c","d","c"))
c<-c(1,0,1)
df<-data.frame(a,b,c, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

ifelse(df$c==1,df$a,df$b)
[1] "a" "d" "a"
```

By default R transforms all columns which contain characters into factors. You have to explicitly tell R that it shall keep the characters.